# Removing duplicated Composer Install in a stage of GitLab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Below you can see a part of my GitLab CI file, I want to remove the `composer install` command in the `demo-tests` stage because it takes more time before my tests and this command has been executed in advance.
If I remove it in this case, I will face the not found autoload file.

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
  - release

composer:
  cache:
    key: "legacy_app"
    paths:
      - vendor/
  stage: build
  image: composer:1.9.3
  script:
    - composer install
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event") && $SKIP_COMPOSER != "true"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[ci b]/

#################################### Staging(Develop) ########################################
demo-docker-build:
  cache:
    key: "legacy_app"
    paths:
      - vendor/
    policy: pull
  stage: build
  image: x:latest
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://dockerbuilder.adminstuff:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  before_script:
    - git clone --depth 1 -b "main" https://x
    - docker login -u x -p x x
    - cp x/Dockerfile ./
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg PROXY_CRED=$PROXY_CRED --network=host --build-arg PROXY_CRED=$PROXY_CRED -t $CI_REGISTRY_PRIVATE/staging:latest ./
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_PRIVATE/staging:latest
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event") && $SKIP_BUILD != "true"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[ci b]/
  environment:
    name: development
  needs:
    - job: composer
      artifacts: true

demo-tests:
  stage: test
  image:
    name: $CI_REGISTRY_PRIVATE/staging:latest
    pull_policy: always
  before_script:
    - composer install
  script:
    
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit:
        - report.xml
        - api/tests/_output/report.xml
    expose_as: 'phpunit-coverage'
    paths:
      - 'coverage/'
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event") && $SKIP_TESTS != "true"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[ci b]/
  environment:
    name: development
```

Comment: The demo-tests:script: child tag is empty in this file. Have you redacted, or did you leave it empty on purpose? I'm not sure script tags can be empty.

Comment: I've also noticed that you're running composer install in the build stages, but you're not sharing the cache from the build stages to the demo-test job in the test stage. If you want to share results of previous jobs to following jobs, you have to use cache or artifacts. See:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#how-cache-is-different-from-artifacts

Comment: I make the script empty just to shorten the code for example. @JoaoCunha

Answer (score 0):

The demo-test job has no cache or artifacts from the previous stage where you've previously run `composer install`. To be able to make use of the results of pre-running this command on subsequent jobs, you need to use either cache or artifacts, as per https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#how-cache-is-different-from-artifacts.

I see that you already use cache in other jobs, so try simply extending that for the demo-test job. Let me know if this works for you.

Also note that your cache seems to be kind of global right now. A better approach to share cache between jobs is to create a cache per branch: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#share-caches-between-jobs-in-the-same-branch. You define this via the cache key:

```
cache:
  key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
```

---

GitLab also provides official docs with a PHP-Composer example which uses a default cache that gets shared between all jobs of the same branch name. This also confirm that it's very important to set the cache key to `$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG`, so that you don't get cache colisions between pipelines. See the Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-php-dependencies

Could you please try this example with the default cache?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work with cache or artifact as well. I tried to set the cache like the below code: 

cache:
     key: "legacy_app"
     paths:
       - vendor/
     policy: pull

Comment: It says something like: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class ComposerAutoloaderInit51dbb5519fac9b007c003d914d89fb5f, because the name is already in use in /builds/legacy/app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 5

Comment: or sometimes : PHP Warning:  require(/app/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/yii_test on line 10

Comment: @MeysamZarei, two things to note. The key "legacy_app" is shared between all the pipelines from different branches. So you should concatenate the branch name in the cache key, like I've explained above, so that your cache is not overridden by a different branch pipeline. Second, the fact that you get "nam is already in use in .../vendor/... seems to show that the cache loading actually worked. From this point on, your question is not a GitLab CI/CD question anymore, but rather a PHP/Composer question. I added the PHP tag to your question to bring attention to PHP specialists.

Comment: But to just confirm that your cache worked, you can simply run `ls vendor` before any other command in that job, and check whether there are files in there. Remember also rename the cache key from the build jobs to also include the branch name.

Comment: Lastly, I've also extended my answer to include official GitLab example on how to set up the cache with PHP and Composer.